# Adding date picker as parameter in BIRT

Tags: javascript, datepicker, birt

I am having some challenges adding a date picker for my date parameter in an Eclipse report. I have little or no knowledge of Javascript ... I would appreciate some detailed instruction on how to accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this, but it is not straight forward.

Here is how,

1. First you need to download the jscal2 project files.You will find the required files in the below mentioned Github project.

   https://github.com/captainhcg/GFW/tree/master/js/JSCal2-1.9
2. In your project find "FramesetFragment.jsp" file located in the location

   > birt/webcontent/birt/pages/layout/FramesetFragment.jsp

   This file should be readily available in your current project setup, if you already have birt report up and running.
   (I am not going to explain birt report configuration in a JAVAEE web project here, because this is only about 
   how to add the datepicker for existing birt report date parameter field.)
3. Add the following lines of code after line number 130(before the `</HEAD>` tag) of "FramesetFragment.jsp" file. Replace the context root path with your
   project context root.

```html
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jscal2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/lang/en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/border-radius.css" meda="screen" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/jscal2.css" meda="screen" type="text/css"/>
```

4. Add the relevant files(4 files) into specified locations in your project

   4.1 Add both jscal2.js and en.js files into javascript file location in your project.

   `yourwebcontextroot/js/jscal2.js`

   `yourwebcontextroot/js/lang/en.js` (* At least one language file is required)

   4.2 Add both style sheets to relevant locations.

   `yourwebcontextroot/css/border-radius.css`

   `yourwebcontextroot/css/jscal2.css`
5. Find "TextBoxParameterFragment.jsp" file located in

   > "birt/webcontent/birt/pages/parameter/TextBoxParameterFragment.jsp"
6. Add the following code just before the last table data and table row end tags of "TextBoxParameterFragment.jsp" file.

```html
<%
if (parameterBean.getParameter().getDataType()==7|| parameterBean.getParameter().getDataType()==4) {
%>

<button id="<%=parameterBean.getName()%>_button">...</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup({
        trigger    : '<%=parameterBean.getName()%>_button',
        inputField : '<%=parameterBean.getName()%>',
                onSelect   : function() { this.hide() }
    });
</script>


<%
}
%>
 </TD>`<!-- Last table data end tag -->`
</TR>`<!-- Last table row end tag -->`
```

7. Thats all. Redeploy your project.Open a new browser window and go to one of your reports.

   You should see a button next to date fields and once you clicked on it, you will get a datepicker window.

   Note:

   Both "FramesetFragment.jsp" and "TextBoxParameterFragment.jsp" files could be in different locations in your project.