# How to insert datepicker in BIRT frameset?

Tags: datepicker, birt, frameset

I am using BIRT runtime 4.3.2. I want to modify birt framset with datepicker. So after selecting date from date picker, I can limit the result accordingly. If anyone has implemented it then please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding date picker as parameter in BIRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555031/adding-date-picker-as-parameter-in-birt)