# Calendar Picker in Birt Report Parameter

Tags: datepicker, report, birt

Does someone know if it is possible to replace a simple text box with a calendar picker in birt report?
I have to make a report with some parameters and some are Date field: for now I use a text box with a specific format for post. But if it is possible I want to change this behavior.

I use Birt Report Designer 4.3.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php/topic/11498-birt-datepicker-plzzzzzzzzzzz/

Comment: [View](http://terrarum.net/blog/adding-a-calendar-widget-to-birt.html) this tutorial it helps u lot but for date picker u need to download JSCal2

Comment: @SundarG a link to another site is not a possible duplicate.  It is a potential reference for an answer though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding date picker as parameter in BIRT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555031/adding-date-picker-as-parameter-in-birt)